# Pre-Computing Nested Data Set MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I am implementing an application where I need to pre-compute some stats and using `aggregation` to show computed results through APIs.

I store all data set on unit day computation. Means for one day, I compute all stats and store those in one MongoDB document. So far linear structure of computing works.

Now I have following complex scenario where multiple inter-related items are encountered. Look at the sample data

```
data = [
    {id: 1 , date: '29-08-2016', service: 'Good', text: 'R1', categories: ['10-20', 'Male', 'Speed', 'Service']},
    {id: 2 , date: '29-08-2016', service: 'Good', text: 'R2', categories: ['51+', 'Female', 'Strength', 'Service']},
    {id: 3 , date: '29-08-2016', service: 'Good', text: 'R3', categories: ['21-50', 'Male', 'Speed']},
    {id: 4 , date: '29-08-2016', service: 'Bad', text: 'R4', categories: ['10-20', 'Female', 'Flexibility']},
    {id: 5 , date: '29-08-2016', service: 'Bad', text: 'R5', categories: ['21-50', 'Female']}
]
```

So I compute linear information from above data set into a MongoDB document:

```
{
   date: '29-08-2016',
   total: 5, 
   sub_total: {
      'Good': 3,
      'Bad': 2
   }
}
```

Now I need to pre-compute count of categories as well. As I do:

```
{
   date: '29-08-2016',
   total: 5, 
   sub_total: {
      'Good': 3,
      'Bad': 2
   },
   categories: {
      '10-20': 2,
      '21-50': 1,
      '51+': 1,
      'Male': 2,
      'Female': 3,
      'Service': 2,
      'Speed': 2,
      'Flexibility': 1,
      'Strength': 1,
   }
}
```

This structure also work if I need to know individual category information. But it gets more complex when I have questions like this:

```
Count of Speed and Service for Female having age 10-20
```

I can't figure out a json structure which can help to answer above questions and using mongodb aggregations.

Any suggestions.

Comment: You are missing the fact that pre-computing is only doable if you know how you will consume your pre-computed data later. The example you have is pretty generic and you are trying to find a way to generically pre-compute all possible queries on this data? If you can put some restrictions around what specific queries you want to pre-compute, then it may be more feasible.